# Testing react-lazyload in React testing library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-lazy-load

I am unit testing a component that makes use of `react-lazyload` to lazyload stuff. While rendering in my unit test, I noticed that the `Lazyload` is not rendering the content and its placeholder is being shown. I tried using waitFor with async/await to wait for lazily loaded content to render in next tick cycle but it still fails and `screen.debug()` still shows the placeholder in the dom.

Is there any way I can test such a component? Here is what I tried:

```
render(<WrapperComponent />)
await waitFor(() => { 
  expect(screen.getByText('Lazily loaded text!')).toBeInTheDocument()
});

// source code
import LazyLoad from 'react-lazyload';
const WrapperComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <LazyLoad placeholder="Loading..." >
        <div>Lazily loaded text!</div>
      </LazyLoad>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Lazily loaded content has a div with the text being expected above.

Answer (score 1):

We can mock the `LazyLoad` component from react-lazyload library at the top of our test file so that the `LazyLoad` component behave just like a wrapper around our actual component that we need to test for.

```
jest.mock(
  'react-lazyload',
  () =>
    function LazyLoad({ children }) {
      return <>{children}</>
    }
)

test('component wrapped with Lazyload', () => {
  const {screen} = render(< WrapperComponent />)
  expect(screen.getByText('Lazily loaded text!')).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Test does not actually trigger real data fetch, you have to mock it.
Probably the function that requests for data should be the one you mock.

Comment: there is no data fetching, the content wrapped in lazyload is not loading. Added code in question.

Comment: Ok, I see now with updated question. I've looked up specs of this package and it seems to be expected behaviour in rendering placeholder instead of content if placeholder is provided. Please take a look at this page https://github.com/twobin/react-lazyload/blob/master/test/specs/lazyload.spec.js#L121

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but how does one test the actual content as placeholder is provided in source code. I was expecting it to replace placeholder with children content in next tick cycle hence used await for that but it is not working like that.

Comment: It would be possible if it was not 3rd party library :] Because that is a disadvantage of 3rd party libraries, that they do not scale, or at this case can't be covered in tests. My suggestion, a bit hacky tho, would to have some sort of flag passed down to child component. It will determine if placeholder is `undefined` (then you can test content) or `"Loading..."` text.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [forceVisible](https://github.com/twobin/react-lazyload#forcevisible):

```js
import { forceVisible } from 'react-lazyload';

it('Testing a component using react-lazyload', async () => {
  const screen = render(<WrapperComponent />)
  forceVisible();

  await waitFor(() => { 
    expect(screen.getByText('Lazily loaded text!')).toBeInTheDocument()
  });
});
```